# How to check if all possible combinations of columns exist in dataframe (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
    A   B   ... 
0   1   1 
1   1   2
2   1   3
0   2   1 
1   2   2
2   2   3
```

And I would like to check if the dataframe is a complete combination of the entries in each column. In the above dataframe this is the case. A = {1,2} B = {1,2,3} and the dataframe contains all possible combinations. Following example would result in a false.

```
    A   B 
0   1   1 
1   1   2
0   2   1
```

The number of columns should be flexible.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'B': [1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

Create a data frame with all combinations of unique values in all columns

```
uniques = [df[i].unique().tolist() for i in df.columns]
df_combo = pd.DataFrame(product(*uniques), columns = df.columns)
print(df_combo)

   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  3
```

Test if two dataframes contain the same elements

```
df.equals(df_combo)
True
```

For False scenario,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2],
                   'B': [1,2,1]})

df_combo
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2

df.equals(df_combo)
False
```

Comment: Hey Rajesh, this seems to work great. Thanks very much! One remark: This is setting up the complete dataframe again, which needs always A*B*[other colums] operations. I wonder if there is also a computational cheaper test possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another option not requiring the generation of a new dataframe would be to just compare the number of de-duplicated combinations to the product of number uniques:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
               'B': [1,2,3,1,2,3],
                'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df[['A','B']].drop_duplicates().shape[0] == df[['A','B']].nunique().prod()
True
```

Comment: I liked the `drop_duplicates` method. I addapted my solution using that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution that I think is "easy to read":

```
from itertools import product

def check_all_possible_combinations_exist(df) -> bool:
    all_posible_combinations = set(product(df['A'], df['B']))
    combinations_in_df_list = df[['A', 'B']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
    combinations_in_df = set([tuple(ba) for ba in baselines])
    return all_posible_combinations.issubset(combinations_in_df)
```